# Unable to install Params::Validate

Tags: perl

I am trying to install **Params::Validate** on `perl 5.10.0`.

Executing `cpan install Params::Validate` will give me the error:

```
can't locate object method "object_file" via package "ExtUtils::CBuilder" at /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/lib/5.10.0/Module/Build/Base.pm line 3935.
```

What is this error and how can I install `Params::Validate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to install the module. It seems like the perl version 5.10.0 didnt have a Module::Build up to date.

Installing the latest version of the module fixed my issue. Hope this helps somebody that meets the same issue.

Comment: Thanks dude! This is what I needed to do to finally install DateTime.